# forbidden:403 error while using wcf restful service

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-403, wcf-rest

I am trying to consume wcf restful service. The code is as follows:

```
private static string SendRequest(string uri, string method, string contentType, string body)
        {
            string responseBody = null;

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            req.Method = method;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
            {
                req.ContentType = contentType;
            }
            if (body != null)
            {
                byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                req.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
                req.GetRequestStream().Close();
            }
            req.Accept = "*/*"; 
            HttpWebResponse resp;

            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            return responseBody;
        }
```

Now the issue is, sometimes it works fine and sometimes i get the error

```
"the remote server returned an error 403 forbidden."
```

I cannot figure out why it fails. Any idea???

Comment: Are you requesting the same URI all the time (when you get the errors, that is). Can you try to catch the exception and check if you can see if there is any sub status (such as the 403.14, directory listing denied)? I think you need to gather some more info in order to sort this out.

Comment: the response text says that, " the underlying connection was closed"

Comment: What about the hosted service? Do you have control over it? Where is it hosted? on what?